# Closest point on ray to triangle in 3D

Tags: triangles, 3d

There's a great many articles on finding the intersecting of a ray and a triangle, or the closest point on a triangle to some other point. However, I can't find anything for finding the closest points between a ray and a triangle.

Perhaps a bit more formally, given the triangle defined by points `A`, `B`, and `C`, and a ray defined by an origin `O` and a direction `D`, find the two points `P` and `Q` where `P` is on the ray, `Q` is on the triangle, and the distance between `P` and `Q` is minimal.

I've tried to start with editing a ray-triangle intersection algorithm, but I don't think that's going to work. A lot of them seem to find where the ray intersects with the plane defined by the triangle, but that's not necessarily the closest point (imagine a ray that is mostly parallel to the plane and slightly above it - the closest point on the ray would be above the triangle, not intersecting its plane).

Has anyone developed an algorithm for this, and if so, what is it?

Comment: Couldn't you just calculate the minimum of $$\{ ||x-y|| \mid x \in L(P_1,P_2),\space y\in R(O,D)\}$$ where $L(P_1,P_2)$ is the line segment defined by two vertices $P_1, P_2$ of the triangle and $R$ is the desired ray. You would get three values, one for each line segment on the triangle, then just take the minimum of those three.

Comment: If the ray does not pierce the triangle, then you need merely test which corner is closest to the ray.

Comment: @RyanK Yeah, finally found an algorithm, where if the ray doesn't pierce the triangle, the closest point on the triangle must be on its edge, which makes sense. It then does the closest point on ray vs segment for each of the triangle edges and returns the minimum.

Comment: Note that the closest point might not be on the edge: consider a ray that starts near the center of the triangle and goes in the direction opposite of the triangle, so that they don't intersect. The closest point will be somewhere near the triangle's center.

Comment: Just a hunch..Let nearest points to the ray through AB,BC,CA be c,a,b respectively ( may lie on extensions of the sides of the triangle) and ortho-center of triangle abc be Q. Drop a perpendicular from Q onto ray  D ...as the desired point P, so that OPQ is a right angle.

Comment: @lisyarus Good point. In the case where the ray is pointing away from the triangle, I can use a nearest-point-on-triangle algorithm on the ray origin, which also has a good amount of literature.

Answer (score 2):

Putting together some stuff from this question's comments:

- First do a regular ray-triangle intersection test. If it passes, the closest point is obviously the intersection.
- <s>If the ray is facing away from the triangle (i.e. the ray's time-of-intersection with the plane defined by the triangle is negative, which most ray-triangle intersections test for), the closest point on the ray is the ray's origin. Can use that point with a standard algorithm to find the corresponding closest point on the triangle.</s>
- Otherwise, the closest point will be on one of the triangle's edges. Run the closest point on ray and line segment algorithm on all 3 of the edges and take the one that's closest.

(For lines parallel to the triangle, there may not be a singular closest point, but that does not matter for my case in particular)

Comment: I don't think point two is quite correct. If the origin of the ray is way off to the side of the triangle and the angle is relatively shallow, the origin won't be the closest point.